# In VisualFlow, is there a way to capture the running user?

Tags: user, visual-flows

Is there a way to pass into VisualFlow the username (or other $User value) so that you know which user is running the flow?

I've tried to use this:

&varAccountID={!Account.Id}&varUserName={!$User.Username}

But this requires two Record Lookups (Account, then User), and the Flow is not retaining the User value. Any idea why?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can put the flow inside a VF page.  If you do this, you can then use a controller and the controller can access the flow and set variables.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not built into flow. My work around is to create a formula field called CurrentUser on the object (Account in your example) with a value of User.Id in the formula. I can then read that value in when I do a record lookup on the object and optionally do a record lookup  of the UserId to get username, email, etc. This works well when running the flow from an Visualforce page/button.